# How to plot nicely-spaced data labels?

Tags: r, plot

Labeling data points in a plot can get unwieldy:
[image]

Randomly sampling few labels may disappoint:
[image]

What would be a nice way to pick a small set of nicely-spaced data labels? That is, to randomly pick representatives whose labels are not overlapping.

```
# demo data
set.seed(123)
N <- 50
x <- runif(N)
y <- x + rnorm(N, 0, x)
data <- data.frame(x, y, labels=state.name)

# plot with labels
plot(x,y)
text(x,y,labels)

# plot a few labels
frame()
few_labels <- data[sample(N, 10), ]
plot(x,y)
with(few_labels, text(x,y,labels))
```

Comment: The example is in R but it's really a generic quesion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do is through clustering. Here is a solution with `stats::hclust`. We agglomerate the data points in cluster and then pick one random observation from each cluster.

```
few_labels <- function(df, coord=1:ncol(df),grp=5){

  require(dplyr)
  df$cl <- cutree(hclust(dist(df[,coord])),grp)
  few_labels <- df %>% group_by(cl) %>%
    do(sample_n(.,1))
  return(few_labels)
}

# demo data
set.seed(123)
N <- 50
x <- runif(N)
y <- x + rnorm(N, 0, x)
data <- data.frame(x, y, labels=state.name)

# plot a few labels
frame()
few_labels <- few_labels(data,coord=1:2,grp=12)
plot(x,y)
with(few_labels, text(x,y,labels))
```

[image]

Comment: No libraries? Isn't that dplyr?

Comment: @MikeWise There's a `require` in the function definition.

Answer (score 2):

For all labels:

```
xlims=c(-1,2)
plot(x,y,xlim=xlims) 
#text(x,y,data$labels,pos = 2,cex=0.7)
library(plotrix)
spread.labels(x,y,data$labels,cex=0.7,ony=NA)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to pick randomly a point, throw all proximate ones, and so on, until no point is left:

```
radius <- .1 # of a ball containing the largest label

d <- as.matrix(dist(data[, c("x","y")], upper=TRUE, diag=TRUE))
remaining <- 1:N
spaced <- numeric()
i <- 1
while(length(remaining)>0) {
  p <- ifelse(length(remaining)>1, sample(remaining, 1), remaining)  
  spaced <- c(spaced, p)  # ...   
  remaining <- setdiff(remaining, which(d[p, ] < 2*radius))
  i <- i + 1
}

frame()
plot(x,y)
spaced_labels <- data[spaced, ]
with(spaced_labels, text(x,y,labels))
```

[image]